# Which file load first in android studio while run the application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, build.gradle

I have one stupid confusing question , in eclipse , Manifest file load first while run the android application.

But in android studio project which file load first , out of ,

```
        - build.gradle  file  or

        - Manifest file ?
```

which of one above called first ?

because build.gradle file also contains,

```
        - compileSdkVersion 
        - buildToolsVersion    and default config having following,


        - applicationId 
        - minSdkVersion 
        - targetSdkVersion
        - versionCode 
        - versionName
```

thank you.

Comment: Android Studio is IDE and doesn't call anything from manifest. Android does.

Comment: I understand your question if you use gradle to build your app then the setting you have in manifest will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

This is what Android has to say about this officially :
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

And some further reading :

"Introducing Gradle and the Manifest"
https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/introducing-gradle-and-the-manifest

Answer (score 0):

gradle is for compiling and indexing the app files while manifest is the file which loaded when you run the app the android system looks into the manifest file to check the hardware requirements that the app needs